# Load nodes and create relations from a single csv file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have to load a CSV file having an id (cui), and a name of a disease, some of the ids are repeating themselves but they have a slightly different name. I would like to create the nodes with unique id and nodes for all the other names which are slightly different. the nodes with alternative name will have a relationship `[:HAS_ALTERNATIVE_NAME]` with the initial nodes.

I have a query which is appending the alternative names in the node property, this time I will like to normalize the problem by creating a node for each alternative name.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Concepts_50000.csv' AS line 
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MERGE (d:Disease{id: line.CUI})
ON CREATE SET 
    d.prefered_name = line.name,
    d.alternative_name = line.name
ON MATCH SET
    d.alternative_name = d.alternative_name+', '+line.name;
```

In the end, I will like to have something like this situation, one disease having alternative names nodes.

[image: Ideal result of the querry]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do what you want:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///input.csv' AS line 
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MERGE (d:Disease {id: line.CUI})
MERGE (n:DiseaseName {name: line.name})
MERGE (d)-[: HAS_ALTERNATIVE_NAME]->(n)
```

[UPDATED]

For better performance, make sure you have [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on:

- `:Disease(id)`
- `:DiseaseName(name)`

Comment: this query is doing exactly what I need but in a large set of data is not performant. Is there another way of achieving my goal maybe using the apoc library?